# How can i access Return value throught the construct() from another function In PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, php-7, php-7.2

I'm trying to access the return value of the `test()` inside `__constructor()` but I stucked it. anyone Can tell me about that how can I get the return value from `__constructor()`. I appreciate your answer!

```
class some
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->test(); // I want this test()
    }

    public function test() 
    {
        return 'abc';
    }
}

$some = new some;


echo $some;

print_r($some);
```

I tried by myself, but nothing happens!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructors don't return values and you can't just echo an object, try this instead.

```
class some
{
    private $my_string;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->my_string = 'abc';
    }

    public function test() 
    {
        return $this->my_string;
    }
}

$some = new some;


echo $some->test();
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to implement the `__toString()` in your class

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->test();
}
```

Print your object

```
echo $some; // 'abc'
```

---

---

You can improve your code:

```
class Some
{
    protected $test;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->test = $value;
    }

    public function __toString()
{
    return 'Your Value: ' . $this->test;
}
}

$some = new Some('Hello World');

echo $some; // Your Value: Hello World
```

Comment: Wow Inspiration Yaar Thank's